# How to change keys for info command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do you change the key configuration for the info command?

I'm using the mode --vi-keys but I want to change the follow hypertext link key to RET since it was changed to be moving 1 line down in --vi-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the "follow hypertext link" save the following at `~/.infokey`

```
#info
\r   select-reference-this-line
```

Then loat it:

```
$ infokey
```

To make it persistent you can include `infokey` on your `~/.bashrc`.

The [full documentations is here](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Custom-Key-Bindings).

Comment: Thank you very much. How do you know what to put in .infokey?

Comment: You are welcome. I've found the information on the documentation (the link is on the last line of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

The key configuration is hard-coded in `info`. You can not change it, unless you download the sources, modify and build your own version.

You can use `CTRL-X RET` instead though.

Comment: I hate that shortcut though!

Comment: I agree, `CTRL-X RET` sounds more like an `emacs` shortcut.